# Sorting Listview Java

Tags: java, android, listview, sorting

I wish to sort my listView by the variable called score. Anybody know how to do this? Currently here is my code that get's information from a database and displays it in a list view.

```
 List<String> queryTable(){
    List<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        int score = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score"));
        player.add(id + " --> the player " + name + " has got a score of " + score +"s");
    }
```

So how would I go about sorting this listview by the variable "score"? Thanks guys.

Comment: try it using comparable

Comment: get the information from database already sorted. There's sql keywords for this `ORDERY BY columnname` You can add `ASC` or `DESC` to get it ascending or descending

Answer (score 1):

Last parameter of the `query` function is used to sort. Just replace null with

```
column_name + " DESC".
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to work it just crashes when I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

List has sort functionality for elements. This is the sample code:

```
List<Fruit>  fruits= new ArrayList<Fruit>();
Fruit fruit;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   fruit = new fruit();
   fruit.setname(...);
   fruits.add(fruit);
}
//Sorting
Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Fruit  fruite1, Fruit  fruite2)
    {

        return  fruite1.fruitName.compareTo(fruite2.fruitName);
    }
});
```

This code sorts the list according to furitName property. When we look your code, you can do the same thing. Firstly, you have to use a class that represents the id,name and score. Using this class, you can add and sort elements using List.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the records in a list and then apply sorting(depending on your variable called score) and then notify the list with this updated and sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

call this method:

Collections.sort(score_list, myComparator);

here is your comparator:

Comparator myComparator = new Comparator() {

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
        int i1 = lhs;
        int i2 = rhs;
        return (i1 -i2);
    }
};
```